# Animate movement of an image

Tags: css, jquery-animate

First a little code =] :

css:

```
.mainnav li:hover{
   background:url("/css/images/nav.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.mainnav li').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate(????,400)
  });
});
```

html:

```
<ul class="mainnav">
  <li>
   <a href="/Home.aspx">home</a>
  </li>
  ..
  ..
</ul>
```

What I want is that when the mouse gets over an other li the image doesnt move/pop right away, rather it'll move slowly("animated") to there..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To animate background position you need a [plugin](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/) as jquery doesn't do it out of the box. Usage on the linked page.

Comment: You can put another element inside li, 400px tall and positioned absolutely and animate it's `top` property. Ofcourse your li needs to have `overflow:hidden`. You trade unnecessary plugin for unnecessary element, but it is a good way to achieve the effect you're after.